# How can I create a C# Delegates that does not return?

Tags: c#, delegates

Since Func<> delegates does not take "void" how could i acieve the following in C# 3.0

```
Func<int, int, void> delg = (a, b) => { Console.WriteLine( a + b); };
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use Action instead of Func.

```
    Action<int, int> delg = (a, b) => { Console.WriteLine( a + b); };
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to `Action<int, int>` you can create your own delegate and return and pass in whatever types you want.

```
public delegate void MyDelegate(int val1, int val2);
```

use:

```
MyDelegate del = (a, b) => {Console.WriteLine( a + b); };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Func<int, int, Action> foo = (a, b) => () => Console.Out.WriteLine("{0}.{1}", a, b);
        foo(1, 2)();
```

Answer (score 0):

Func and Action are delegate wrappers, Funcs return a value (the name might come from VBs function..?) and Actions dont.

Like CSharpAtl said, since they are both wrappers, you could just as well make your own delate, with a name that makes more sense to you, (like `VoidFunc(int val1 ,int val2))`, thought I think `Func` and `Action` are pretty standard.